# How to keep backward comapatiblity in styles

Tags: android, android-studio, android-styles

In my styles I have something below

```
<style name="Label">
   <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

But this code requires API level 16. Is there any way to implement a fallback mechanism inside style for API level less than 16?
In java code I could have done something like below

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    // set font style
} else {
    // Do not set font style
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use the resource filters - just put your styles.xml file in the right folder - e.g. values-v16